# Kubernetes readinessProbe initialDelaySeconds Doesn't working

Tags: kubernetes

I try to tell to K8s that my Pod is ready by the time there is a connection to MongoDB and Redis and an Express server is on.
I have configured: `initialDelaySeconds: 60` but the Pod is getting ready too soon after 20s, approximately:

[image]

See the 21s in the above picture..

Note: even if I configure to 5s, it takes around 20s anyways.

Comment: Can you share your Kube config yaml file for this deployment ?

Comment: Update: I came along with this. I applied `startupProbe` and then `readinessProbe`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came along with this. Configuring a `startupProbe` before the `readinessProbe` fixed the issue for me.

```
      startupProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /health/?startup_probe=1
          port: 3003
        initialDelaySeconds: 3
        periodSeconds: 1
        timeoutSeconds: 5
      readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /health
          port: 3003
        initialDelaySeconds: 3
        periodSeconds: 3
        timeoutSeconds: 5
```

Such a way fixed the issue and also makes sure that the Pod is up and running even after its ready.

Notice that I added a `startup_probe` param so in the `startupProbe` which is only one time it will make a big check against the databases and in the `readinessProbe` it will just check against the API without invoking databases calls.